# Marklogic index children

Tags: xml, indexing, xquery, marklogic

Is it possible to index on children elements?

My data is setup like this

```
    <schedule id="ID_HERE" lang="LANGUAGE">
    <scheduleItem id="CHILD_NODE_ID" lang="eng">
        <dateTime>
            2015-01-19T00:00:09-00:00
        </dateTime>
    </scheduleItem>
    <scheduleItem id="CHILD_NODE_ID1" lang="eng">
        <dateTime>
            2015-01-19T00:00:09-00:00
        </dateTime>
    </scheduleItem>
    <scheduleItem id="CHILD_NODE_ID2" lang="eng">
        <dateTime>
            2015-01-19T00:00:09-00:00
        </dateTime>
    </scheduleItem>
</schedule>
```

There are multiple schedules in my database.

I am trying to get the number of `scheduleItems` that fit the result of a search - e.g.: the count of all scheduleItems with `/@lang = eng` and `/dateTime < 2015-01-19T00:00:00`

I am using search:search to query these items, but the resulting `/@total` of the search is the number of schedules, not the number of schedule items.

I also found when I do a `xdmp:estimate(/schedule/scheduleItem)` it returns the number of schedules, not the number of scheduleItems.

`fn:count()` returns the correct number but, I would like to stay clear of `fn:count()` if it is slow and not using indexes.

Is there a way to get the number of scheduleItems using `xdmp:estimate()` or `search:search()`?

I am looking into Field Range Indexes

Comment: I also tried a `search:search()` with an option of `<return-results>false</return-results>` this only returned the number of schedules

Comment: You could create a fragment root on `<scheduleItem>`, but generally, fragment roots are not a good idea except for some very specific scenarios. You would need to provide more information about the content in your database and exactly what kind work the application does for someone to determine if that's appropriate.

Comment: @wst 
as I understand it, a fragment root would make my `<scheduleItem>`s indexed just as if they were documents? What is the downside? Would it be worse to have each `<scheduleItem>` in a separate document? (they are about ~430 characters long)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MarkLogic indexes all elements by default. The problem here is that you're treating a document like a table. Documents act more like rows. I recommend creating one document per `scheduleItem` element. The schedule could be a URI prefix, creating a virtual directory like `"/schedules/"||$id||"/"`. Documents averaging 430-B would be a little small, but size is less important than designing the document structure so that it matches your application.

You could also consider a fragment root on `scheduleItem`. But in the long run I think you'd be better off with multiple documents.

Comment: What is the downside of having fragment roots? I ~would~ like to keep scheduleItems as children of schedule as I am adding and deleting schedules as a whole. but it would not too hard to break off scheduleItems into separate files.

Comment: My main objection to fragment roots is that they add complexity. The cost of traversing an XPath like `/schedule/scheduleItem` changes, because you're crossing a fragment boundary and fragments drive I/O operations. It's pretty easy to write XPath that accidentally loads all the child fragments, which could be a lot of I/O. I've written about this in some other posts: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmarklogic%5D+fragment+root might help. Or experiment: you can always change the structure later.

Comment: You mentioned range indexes: that might be an option if you enable the position-aware option and have a very limited set of queries to run. Basically you'd be pulling all your results directly from `cts:values`, instead of using `search:search` or XPath.

Answer (score 2):

I would also recommend splitting the doc, but if you are willing to create a range index, you might be able to do something like this:

```
fn:sum(
  for $v in cts:element-attribute-values(
    xs:QName('scheduleItem'),
    xs:QName('lang'),
    (),
    "item-frequency"
  )
  return cts:frequency($v)
)
```

That will pull all unique values from the value lexicon of the range index, grab value counts for those all from index, and only needs to do a sum at run-time to find the total.

The cts:*-values functions also take an extra parameter to restrict to for instance on schedules containing scheduleItems within a particular date range. That will include false positives though if you don't split your docs into individual scheduleItems, or apply a fragment root as suggested by Michael..

HTH!